# I Have 2 1064 SQL Errors And Can Not Figure Them Out

Tags: mysql-error-1064

This code worked good on ph 5.3. My server got upgraded to php5.6 and now the code no longer works.

Here is the two statements.

```
$sql = "UPDATE " . FORUM_TOUR_TABLE . "
            SET page_subject = '$subject', page_text = '$message', page_access = $page_access
            WHERE page_id = $id";
```

It says :

`SQL Error : 1064 Syntax error near 'WHERE page_id = 1' at line 3

UPDATE SET phpbb_forum_tour page_subject = ' Welcome To The Tower' , page_text = ' Update me please ' = WHERE page_access page_id = 1

Line : 172
File: admin_forum_tour.php`

That happens when I try to update a post.

When I try to add a new post using this code:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO " . FORUM_TOUR_TABLE . " (page_id, page_subject, page_text, page_sort, bbcode_uid, page_access)
            VALUES ($id, '$subject', '$message', $page, '$bbcode_uid', $page_access)";
```

This gives me this:

`SQL Error : 1064 Syntax error near ')' at line 2

INSERT INTO phpbb_forum_tour ( page_id , page_subject , page_text , page_sort , bbcode_uid , page_access ) VALUES (3, '2 Word Rule ', ' Hello World I am here ', 30 , ' f4e1be18dc ' )

Line : 198
File: admin_forum_tour.php`

I 100% apologize for asking this as I am more than sure it has been beat to death. I have been searching for a couple hours now and have all but given up. I had it working once but was told I opened my self up to injection. I am not a pro coder. I get lucky sometimes and make things work. I am sure these errors and code is basic to most but I am still learning.

Thanks for helping and understanding my "newbieness".

Comment: Is FORUM_TOUR_TABLE a defined constant or the name of the table?

Comment: forum_tour is the name of the table

Comment: Just to verify the syntax errors, I ran the code through SQL Fiddle and it came back with errors there too.

Comment: Why do you have FORUM_TOUR_TABLE in your query? Is this a defined constant somewhere?

Comment: If I put tick marks on either side of $page_access both sql querys work. However, that is a integer not a string. I was told I open my self up to injection that way.

Comment: @The One and Only ChemistryBlob that is the way all the sql query are in phpBB forums. Not sure why it is that way. I am a very long time user, just  a newbie trying his hand at code. Not sure how else it would update that table otherwise (??).

Comment: And yes it is defined like this: `define('FORUM_TOUR_TABLE', $table_prefix.'forum_tour'); `

Comment: I figured it out and got everything working.